# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1... but it does

Tags: mysql

I made a mysqldump of only data with about 10000+ INSERTS from a table. When I try to restore it in another database I get "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" in some rows, all other rows are restored without problems, so I asume it's not table definition problem.

For example, this works:

```
INSERT INTO `DATOS_TRAFICO_DESC1` VALUES (732,'2011-11-05','732/1111/D',0,' ','I','02102508791016','ADIEL ALBERTO VASQUEZ MIRANDA','C61997',0,' ','CONTENEDOR','SV02233','GT110088097','2018437',' ','2001-01-01','00:00:00','2011-11-09','13:29:33','Bueno','SMLU8504427',0,'','2001-01-01','','','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','');
```

This doesn't works:

```
INSERT INTO `DATOS_TRAFICO_DESC1` VALUES (729,'2011-11-07','729/1111/D',0,' ','I','11050900042600','ELBER REYES PEREZ','C130BLQ',0,' ','FURGON','GTY54','SV110246035','321453',' ','2001-01-01','00:00:00','2011-11-07','08:46:06','Bueno','TC99BSL',0,'','2001-01-01','','','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','');
```

Same thing with complete inserts.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Here are the SHOW CREATE for the source table:

```
CREATE TABLE `DATOS_TRAFICO_DESC1` (
  `Carta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `Deposito` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Correlativo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Declaracion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo_Operacion` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `Licencia` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Motorista` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Codigo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Codigo_Cia` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre_Cia` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Clase_Vehiculo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `No_Vehiculo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `DMTI_o_GTO` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Marchamo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Usuario_creador` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_creado` date NOT NULL,
  `Hora_creado` time NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_Entrada_Contenedor` date NOT NULL,
  `Hora_Entrada_Contenedor` time NOT NULL,
  `Estado_Marchamo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Codigo_del_contenedor` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad_Contenedores` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `DMTI` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_DMTI` date NOT NULL,
  `Manifiesto_Carga` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Copia_carta_aceptacion` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Declaracion_Mercaderia` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Carta_porte_BL_Guia_aerea` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Factura_comercial` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Lista_empaque` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Nota_remision` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Modificable` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Finalizado` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Fecha`,`Carta`,`Deposito`,`Correlativo`,`Declaracion`,`Tipo_Operacion`,`Codigo_del_contenedor`),
  KEY `Nombre` (`Codigo_Cia`),
  KEY `Deposito` (`Deposito`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here for the destination table

```
CREATE TABLE `DATOS_TRAFICO_DESC1` (
  `Carta` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Fecha` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1901-01-01',
  `Deposito` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Correlativo` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Declaracion` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Tipo_Operacion` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Licencia` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Motorista` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Codigo` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Codigo_Cia` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Nombre_Cia` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Clase_Vehiculo` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `No_Vehiculo` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DMTI_o_GTO` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Marchamo` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Usuario_creador` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Fecha_creado` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1901-01-01',
  `Hora_creado` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `Fecha_Entrada_Contenedor` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1901-01-01',
  `Hora_Entrada_Contenedor` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `Estado_Marchamo` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Codigo_del_contenedor` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Cantidad_Contenedores` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DMTI` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Fecha_DMTI` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1901-01-01',
  `Manifiesto_Carga` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Copia_carta_aceptacion` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Declaracion_Mercaderia` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Carta_porte_BL_Guia_aerea` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Factura_comercial` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Lista_empaque` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Nota_remision` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Modificable` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `Finalizado` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Fecha`,`Carta`,`Deposito`,`Correlativo`,`Declaracion`,`Tipo_Operacion`,`Codigo_del_contenedor`),
  KEY `Codigo_Cia` (`Codigo_Cia`),
  KEY `Deposito` (`Deposito`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Could you post the table create statement in order to try to duplicate the symptom

Comment: Sure, check the edit.

Comment: I created both tables and could properly insert both insert statements in it.  So I cannot duplicate your issue. Maybe it is related to the client tool you use. I could imagine that it adds linebreaks which could breaks the statement. Both inserts are very simular and I cannot see any (obvious) cause.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also try to insert individual lines and I always get the error message. However, just like you, if I create both tables and make the both insert statements gets no error. The same applies if I make a backup/restore on these newly created table.